# Know whether user downloaded iOS app for free or paid?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

I am switching my iOS app which is already on the app store from paid to free.  I want to know which users have paid for the app, so I can treat them differently (like not showing them additional ads).  As far as I know, there's no way to get which version of the app users originally downloaded.

One thing I thought of is this.  I can release an update at the same time the app goes free.  Everyone who launches the game for the first time who has the update gets marked with a "Free Download" flag.  The issue here is what if someone paid for the app, then didn't launch it, then updated their app.  That means I will treat them like a free user even though they have paid.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this with 100% accuracy without releasing a new app.

If you do use a flag of some sort, save the flag in the keychain and/or iCloud so that it will have a better chance of persisting across uninstall/reinstalls and from device to device (if you use iCloud).

Your best bet though is probably to release a new lite version of the app. It can be a pain to maintain two versions, but at least you know for sure who's paid and who hasn't.

Comment: Dang, that's not what I wanted to hear.  I'll leave this open for a sec to see if anyone else has ideas, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I somewhat accomplish this with a server-side script. On initial app launch, I grab data from my server to determine if this is a paid or free install and then save this info in iCloud. It works relatively well, but it does have a drawback; a small percentage of the time the query fails. If it fails, I just set the app as being paid so as not to screw anyone over. This screws me over a bit, but I take the hit for the convenience of not having to update whenever I want to switch paid/free.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot show updates or advertisement for the customers separately who bought the app for free or by paying money. Whenever you changed your paid app to free, the customers can download the application for free now.